# SQL decimal places within a select statement

Tags: sql, decimal

I've been reading threads and seeing the 'Convert' and 'Cast' commands, but I cannot get any to fit in this simple select statement.  Very frustrating to have to ask a question this simple, but I cannot find anything that works.  Below is the code, and I need the 'discount amount/price' to show up with 2 decimal places.  Thank you in advance.

```
select product_name, list_price, discount_percent, list_price * 
(discount_percent*.01) as 'discount_amount', 
list_price - (list_price * (discount_percent*.01)) as 'discount_price'
from products
order by discount_price desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: which rdbms ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database should give you back a decimal/numeric type that is **capable of** storing the fractional digits, but the results grid and/or your application is still responsible for how to **display** those digits.

Your query looks like it does implicit casting, but you can explicitly do it like this:

```
select 
    product_name, list_price, discount_percent, list_price * 
    (cast(discount_percent as decimal(18,2)) * .01) as 'discount_amount', 
    cast(list_price as decimal(18,2)) - (cast(list_price as decimal(18,2)) * (cast(discount_percent as decimal(18,2)) * .01)) as 'discount_price'
from products
order by discount_price desc
limit 5;
```

Your displayed query results might still do its own rounding and display, for example "5" instead of "5.00", but that is because your UI still needs to implement it's own logic to display whatever format you're looking for.

Comment: The code functions properly, but the numbers still show up with multiple decimals.  https://i.imgur.com/qoibJGW.png

Comment: They will show up that way until you explicitly format them in the UI / application.  That's what I'm saying - the db has done the job of giving you a decimal data type, but the db doesn't render it to the screen - that's the job of the "results grid" or your application code, so you need to ALSO do a String.Format or whatever in the UI to complete the task.

Comment: What SlimsGhost said: display should be handled on the view side of things. Though I wouldn't truncate each piece until you're done with the math: `CAST(list_price - (list_price * (discount_percent*.01)) AS decimal(10,2)) as 'discount_price'`  Also, pay attention to the datatypes of `list_price` and `discount_price`.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use round or truncate:

```
SELECT ROUND(12.545, 2) 
SELECT TRUNCATE(12.545, 2)
```

in MS SQL, you can Convert:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ColumName) FROM TableName
```